# How to Add Selection from Selectbox To Database On Submission

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu

I have a form which I am submitting and all of the data saves to the "Orders" model.  One of the fields is an html selectbox, so when I submit the form, it does not save to the model.  I am looking to figure out how I can make that dropdown selection save like the rest of the data.

Forms.py

```
class CreateOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ('reference', 'ultimate_consignee', 'ship_to')
```

ADD_ORDER.HTML

```
  <div class="column_order">
        <label for="form.reference">Reference ID: </label>
        {{ form.reference }}
        <br>
        <label> Ultimate Consignee:
         <br>
        <select class="select-css">
          {% for element in objectlist %}
            <option value="{{ element.c_name }}">{{ element.c_name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="form.ship_to">Ship To: </label>
        <br>
        {{ form.ship_to }}
  </div>
```

Views.py (to illustrate how I am filling the selectbox above)

```
def add_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateOrderForm(request.POST)
        objectlist = Customers.objects.all()


        if form.is_valid():
            reference_id = form.cleaned_data.get('reference')
            form.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest')
    else:
    form = CreateOrderForm()
    objectlist = Customers.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'objectlist': objectlist,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_order.html', context)
```

**EDIT**
Models.py

```
class Customers(models.Model):

    ultimate_consignee = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    c_address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    c_country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def _str_(self):
    return self.ultimate_consignee

class Orders(models.Model):

    reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ultimate_consignee = models.ForeignKey(Customers, blank=True)
    ship_to = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    vessel = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    booking_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    POL = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    DOL = models.DateField(blank=True)
    COO = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    POE = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    ETA = models.DateField(blank=True)
    pickup_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    terms = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    sales_contact = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    trucking_co = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    loading_loc = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    inspector = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    total_cases = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    total_fob = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    freight_forwarder = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    commodity = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    is_airshipment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)

def _str_(self):
    return self.reference
```

As you can see, the selectbox which I create in the .html file is not really related to the form.  And so no data from the selection is being saved to the Orders model which is what I am looking to make happen here.  Any recommendations?

Comment: can you share your model as well? But it sounds like the `Orders` model has a `ForeignKey` to `Customers`, which is of course the sensible way to associate each order with the customer who placed it - in that case you should simply need to add that field to the `fields` tuple in your form's `class Meta`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have generated the select list separately at all, rather than just having it as another field on CreateOrderForm.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've updated the question to include the models.  Ultimate_Consignee basically translates to customer name in real life terms so that field is already added in forms, not sure what to do.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did it this way because the choices of the select list are being populated with all entries in the Customer model dynamically.  This was the only way I could find to do it - is there are more efficient way? It did seem very roundabout to me...

Comment: As I said, that is exactly the default behaviour anyway. The ForeignKey on the model maps to a ModelChoiceField on the form, which is automatically populated with all the choices from the related model. Just do `{{ form.ultimate_consignee }}` exactly as you have done with the other fields.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok when I go this way the dropdown just fills with all options listed as "Customers Object".  How do I change that to show the Ultimate_Consignee field? I thought this was done via the model, but I already have return self.ultimate_consignee.

Comment: That is because your str method is a) not indented inside the class and b) misnamed, it should be `__str__` with two underscores each side.

Comment: ahhh thank you sir - appreciate the assistance @DanielRoseman